# I just installed an SSD. How can I check if I'm using it now?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I recently installed an SSD and cloned the files on my 1TB hard disk to it. I tried to boot into it but I'm not sure if it worked. My 1TB HDD is still inside my PC, so the boot into the SSD may have failed, and so my PC simply went on to boot into the HDD. Is there a way to check if my SSD is working and that I am booted into it?

Comment: An easy way to do it would be to just remove the 1TB HDD temporarily (just unplug the power to it) and see if your PC still boots. You could also check the size of `%HOMEDRIVE%` by opening `cmd` and running `dir %HOMEDRIVE%`, which would tell you the size of the disk that Windows is running on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click Windows logo on task bar and select `Disk Management`. Windows will report the drive it's on as the C: drive. You should also see other drives in your machine.

Comment: Got it. Now just need to find way to fix SSD.